# RelayCommand with parameter

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light

I have a function that returns an ICommand (RelayCommand to be precise), and to this function I need to pass some parameters. Here is the code:

```
private ICommand CreateSectionCommand(FilterEnum filterEnum, string title = null, string searchKey = "")
    {
        return new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            NavigationService.Build<SearchPageViewModel>()
                             .WithParam("criteria", new Criteria
                {
                    Query = searchKey,
                    SearchFilter = filterEnum,
                    Title = title
                })
                .Navigate();
        });
    }
```

When I initialize the command, everything is ok, but when I click on the button for navigating, it does nothing. Most probably, the problem is that all the parameters are null because the RelayCommand is invoked on a different time of the initialization.

How can I solve this and pass the correct parameters? I cannot simply bind the CommandParameter property in the XAML.

Edit: just checked my old code, the exact same version worked on Windows 8, but my project is now Windows 8.1.

Comment: "Does nothing" is not really clear. Did you put a breakpoint on that .Navigat()? Is that reached?

Comment: With a breakpoint I see it's never hitted. But if I change the WithParam part with: WithParam("criteria", new Criteria
                {
                    Query = "query",
                    SearchFilter = FilterEnum.X,
                    Title = "title"
                })) it works, the breakpoint is reached and the navigation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind those parameters (in View) to properties of Your ViewModel - I assume that parameters come from some UI elements of Your View (for example search TextBox or filter type ComboBox). Then You will be able to use them in CreateSectionCommand.

But if You can't use binding from View try this:

```
private Criteria commandCriteria;
private ICommand CreateSectionCommand(FilterEnum filterEnum, string title = null, string searchKey = "")
{
    commandCriteria = new Criteria
            {
                Query = searchKey,
                SearchFilter = filterEnum,
                Title = title
            };
    return new RelayCommand(() =>
    {
        NavigationService.Build<SearchPageViewModel>()
                         .WithParam("criteria",commandCriteria )
            .Navigate();
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't, otherwise I could have used the CommandParameter property.

Comment: This works if I have only one item, but I have a list of items and each item has its own command, generated by this function. So doing what you suggested means that it works only with the last item of my list.

Comment: Correct. But in this way I add another object in a very complex view, I'm trying to leave this as a last hope. I was searching for a proper solution such as a particular instance of a RelayCommand that can let me pass the parameter. Something like that:  return new RelayCommand( commandCriteria =>
    {
        NavigationService.Build<SearchPageViewModel>()
                         .WithParam("criteria",commandCriteria )
            .Navigate();
    });